# Bottleneck of motioneyeOS

Tags: pi-3, motion

I am using the motioneyeOS with two [ELP](http://www.elpcctv.com/) webcams connected. When using those, I can only use one camera on a full resolution, while I need to use the second one with only 320x240. Otherwise one, or even two, cameras are disabled. In this case, the `top` command does not even show any heavy processing. It seems that the two cameras do not do anything.

As my use case demands two cameras, and I think `motion` is quite convenient, I am trying to use it on another board. But here I want to be sure to choose the right one and want to know what specs need to change.

So my question is, what is actually the bottleneck here? Is it the lack of RAM, the CPU or even the GPU limited memory (Or even the USB controller)? Unfortunately, I can't really see anything in the logs pointing me into any direction. But the issue seems to be independent of the fps, and only dependent on the resolution.

Comment: Can you run `top` while the program runs and get a sense of what resources are used?

Comment: I edited the post accordingly.